# Achieving a specific button layout

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve the following button layout i drafted in word:

[image]

the "Button 2" and "Button 3" occupies 50 50 of the length of the "Button 1" above, meaning they are of equal width.

I'm having issues where the bottom two buttons are not occupying a 50 50 space like the above picture.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1vw;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
}

#output2 {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 25%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#basic {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#small {
    display: flex;    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href = "style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id = "output2">
    <div id = "basic">
      <button id = "btn1">Button 1</button>
      <div id = "small">
        <button id = "btn2">Button 2</button>
        <button id = "btn3">Button 3</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give `#btn2` and `#btn3` a width of 50% each.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1vw;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
}

#output2 {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 25%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#basic {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#small {
    display: flex;    
}

#btn2, #btn3 {
    width: 50%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href = "style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id = "output2">
    <div id = "basic">
      <button id = "btn1">Button 1</button>
      <div id = "small">
        <button id = "btn2">Button 2</button>
        <button id = "btn3">Button 3</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#btn2, #btn3{
    width: 50%;
}
```

please add the above css code.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox will attempt to shrink Objects along the main axis to fit, but it won't attempt to stretch them to fill out the space by default. (but it will stretch it across the cross axis by default, that is why setting `#basic` to `flex-direction:column` makes Button 1 fill the whole width.)

You can tell the individual flex objects to occupy half of the available space by setting them to `flex-basis:50%`

```css
#basic {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#small {
    display: flex;    
}
.flex-basis-50 { flex-basis: 50%; }
```

```html
<div id = "basic">
  <button id = "btn1">Button 1</button>
  <div id = "small">
    <button id = "btn2" class="flex-basis-50">Button 2</button>
    <button id = "btn3" class="flex-basis-50">Button 3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```